# Using jquery to trigger a file input/fake button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I got this button:

```
<button class="upload-button" type="button">Upload File</button>
```

which I'm using to cover this default input/browse button:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple">
```

however when I'm using this script:

```
$('.upload-button').on('click', function (){
    $('#upload-input').click();
});
```

It does not seem to work, what i want to do is trigger the browse file after the fake button is clicked, i found another post on here where they said that this is because of the visibility of the file input is set to hidden, but when i tried to set it to default, it still did not work. What can the problem be here?

Comment: You sure you are pointing to the right `input`? like `$('#fileinput'').click();` instead of `$('#upload-input').click();`

Answer (score 2):

Use trigger :

```
 $('#upload-input').trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: `.click()` is the same as `.trigger('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit the DOM object instead :

```
$('#upload-input')[0].click();
```

**NOTE :** make sure that you've the id `upload-input` (looks like you need `#fileinput` instead).

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.upload-button').on('click', function (){
  $('#fileinput')[0].click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="upload-button" type="button">Upload File</button> 
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple">
```